# Troubles using fragment with RecyclerView and Retrofit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have this error, actually I don't know about fragments.

*CreatView*

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container,
                false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.inicio);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
        return rootView;
    }
```

*loadJSON void*

```
private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.42:3000/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getCupon()));
            adapter = new CuponAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

*Adapter*

```
public class CuponAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CuponAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Cupon> cupon;

public CuponAdapter(ArrayList<Cupon> cupon) {
    this.cupon = cupon;
}

@Override
public CuponAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.tv_titulo.setText(cupon.get(i).getTitulo());
    holder.tv_empresa.setText(cupon.get(i).getEmpresa());
    holder.tv_descripcion.setText(cupon.get(i).getDescripcion());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cupon.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tv_titulo, tv_descripcion, tv_empresa;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tv_titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
        tv_descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_descripcion);
        tv_empresa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_empresa);
    }
}
}
```

*The Error*

> 12-08 00:00:05.727 1784-1784/com.mighty.cupoferta E/RecyclerView: No
>   adapter attached; skipping layout

This code is based on [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html) link .
But he explains how to put in an activity, how can I put in a fragment?

Comment: have you checked your  arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
        JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getCupon()));
        adapter = new CuponAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Do not depend on network response to set your adapter.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can do it right here.

Then after the network response you can add data to the adapter and call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Answer (score 0):

Well it is because you are setting `adapter` after delay, try to set an empty `adapter` to `recyclerview` before you return `rootView`, then update `adapter` on `Retrofit` callback as in

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container,
                false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.inicio);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyvlerView.setAdapter(new CuponAdapter(new ArrayList<Cupon>()));
        loadJSON();
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set your adapter in the onCreateView function and use .notifyDataSetChanged() in the loadJSON function to notifiy the adapter about the changes in the data like the code below.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container,
            false);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.inicio);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    loadJSON();
    return rootView;
 }
```

and in your adapter class write this

```
private void loadJSON(){
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.42:3000/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
        JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getCupon()));
        adapter = new CuponAdapter(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```